# Scrolling TextView value are cut off

Tags: android, scroll, textview, horizontal-scrolling, marquee

I have a simple TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but **text value is cut off with "..."**, which is the problem?

[image]

Dinamically I have a simple activty with scrolling movement:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        t.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        t.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

**SOLUTION**: not set setMovementMethod but only setSelected(true) if is necessary. See comments in Yvette answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took this out

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

and added the features from your previous question [HorizontalScrollView cut the text in a TextView and autoscorlling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547967/horizontalscrollview-cut-the-text-in-a-textview-and-autoscorlling)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="left"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Title Song and too much information to display in one line."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I with your layout file I still again the same error, I don't know why :(, I use Android 5.0

Comment: Hi, I create a new project and I have the same problem, I have updated my question with my activty code using your layout code...

Comment: Hi, thanks you so much!! So, in a new project it works with nothing, but in my real project I need only "setSelected(true)" without ScrollingMovementMethod :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your XML layout:

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the code: `android:singleLine="true"` from your xml.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I took this out and it worked.

```
tv_notice_desc.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
```